# Mostrar quantidade de linhas de uma tabela javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou querendo mostrar a quantidade de linhas que tem em uma tabela Javascript, consigo com o botão, quando clicava no botão mostrava a quantidade de linhas, mais queria que mostrasse em uma td a quantidade de linha

```
 <table class="table table-striped  d-none" id="table1" >      
    <thead class="table-active" >
      <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
        <input style="width:270px; border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px; font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif" type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary" onclick="contaLinhasTabela('table1');" value="Quantidade de Registros Response" >
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
     <thead class="table-active"  >
      <tr>
        
        <th scope="col">Arquivo</th>
        <th scope="col">Data Criação</th>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
    </tbody> 
</table>



 function contaLinhasTabela(){  
  var table1 = document.getElementById('tbody');  
  var linhas = table1.getElementsByTagName('tr');  
  alert('A Tabela Response possui ' + linhas.length + ' Registros');  
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

crie um td vazio na tabela e atualize o texto dessa td com o número de linhas quando o botão é clicado

exemplo:

```
<table class="table table-striped d-none" id="table1">
  <thead class="table-active">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8">
        <input style="width:270px; border: 1px solid black;
          border-radius: 10px; font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
          font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif"
          type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
          onclick="contaLinhasTabela('table1');"
          value="Quantidade de Registros Response">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <thead class="table-active">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Arquivo</th>
      <th scope="col">Data Criação</th>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" id="qtd-registros"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

depois, atualize a função contaLinhasTabela para buscar o  td vazio e atualizar o seu texto com o número de linha, assim:

```
function contaLinhasTabela() {
  var table1 = document.getElementById('tbody');
  var linhas = table1.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var qtdRegistros = document.getElementById('qtd-registros');

  qtdRegistros.textContent = 'A Tabela Response possui ' + linhas.length + ' Registros';
}
```